# Workflow Foundation 4 Imports panel not refreshed

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I would like to import a new reference into my Workflow Designer, however I encounter a weird problem.

Here's my code to import a reference.

```
var root = GetRootElement();
VisualBasicSettings vbs = VisualBasic.GetSettings(root);
vbs.ImportReferences.Add(new VisualBasicImportReference { Assembly = Assembly.Load("Castle.Core").FullName, Import = "Castle.Core.Configuration.Xml" });

private object GetRootElement()
{
     var modelservice = workflowDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>();
     if (modelservice == null)
         return null;
     var rootmodel = modelservice.Root.GetCurrentValue();
     return rootmodel;
}
```

It works when I load my designer for the first time, the assembly is well added into the hashset ImportReferences then I also see the namespace in the "Imports" panel. But when I call the above method when user picks a dll through a picker dialog, I call the code above, the assembly is also well added to ImportReferences, but the "Imports" panel is not refreshed...

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the namespace is well imported, it was hided in the dropdownlist above.

Here's the most simple code to import a namespace.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/11/02/wf4-adding-vb-namespace-imports-to-your-workflow-programmatically.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [DesignerView.OnReferenceUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.designerview.onreferenceupdated.aspx)? It seems what you're looking for:

> If the referenced assembly is added, the namespaces of the types found
>   in the assembly are added to the list of imported namespaces. If the
>   referenced assembly is removed, the namespaces of the types found in
>   the assembly are removed from the list of imported namespaces.

Usage example:

```
var designerView = workflowDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
designerView.OnReferenceUpdated(assemblyName, true/false);
```

Comment: this looks exactely what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work. I added your example just after my code like that:
var root = GetRootElement();
VisualBasicSettings vbs = VisualBasic.GetSettings(root);
vbs.ImportReferences.Add(new VisualBasicImportReference { Assembly = Assembly.Load("Castle.Core").FullName, Import = "Castle.Core.Configuration.Xml" });var designerView = workflowDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerView>();
designerView.OnReferenceUpdated(Assembly.Load("Castle.Core").FullName, true);

Comment: Btw, do you know what's the difference between adding an assembly like that:
VisualBasicSettings vbs = VisualBasic.GetSettings(root);
vbs.ImportReferences.Add(...)
and like that:
AssemblyContextControlItem acci = this.WorkflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<AssemblyContextControlItem>();
acci.ReferencedAssemblyNames.Add(...)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you on that. Have you tried to call *OnReferenceUpdated* after *acci.ReferencedAssemblyNames.Add*? They seem to complement each other.

Comment: I tried to put after ReferencedAssemblyNames.Add.. it does't work... It looks like we can't update the imports tab

Comment: Surely there is a way. It seems AssemblyContextControlItem is related to the designer itself and VisualBasicSettings is used to import specific namespaces. You should be using a mix of both, but my knowledge is limited on that area. I'll trying it later when I've some spare time.

Comment: good idea Jota, here's how I did. http://pastebin.com/vSu8zcSz It doesn't work, can you take a look and tell me if you see any mistake ?